How to unittest a complex calculation?
In the domain of computer vision, I want to unittest the projection of 3d coordinates to 2d(image) space, and some similar problems. My issue is that I cannot define in terms of numbers, what the expected result should be.
At the moment I "solve" this with "roundtrip" tests, e.g. unproject from 2d to 3d, and then project to 2d again, which should be close to the original if both methods are correct.
Are there any better approaches?

Why can't you define the expected result? You can do these calculations by hand, if necessary, to figure out the correct result...

Simplest way is mock up the same code in a spreadsheet or scratchpad math system environment. The mistakes made in such a cell based environment are usually quite different to the ones made in a procedural programming language. Then you can generate test data painlessly. Roundtrip tests in the main code can be misleading if you have made the same compensating mistake in both implementations.

roundtrips are good. synthetic data is good. -- in terms of justification, regression tests are simplest. you know what the issue was, and you want to test that it doesn't happen anymore. testing against a spec is more of a headache because who is to say that the spec makes sense? -- if the calculation is complex, break it down. then you can be more confident in its parts and the tests for those parts. and then you can integration-test those pieces in combination.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
